# Sympy Empty intersection in code, but working if declaring explicitly

Tags: python, sympy

In the code, I am trying to get the intersection of a line and the polygon, but it showing an empty intersection.

```
#code snippet
#rot val is -1.2476679904445084e-10
from sympy import Point,Line, Polygon
L = Line(Point(h//2,w//2),slope = math.tan(math.radians(90 - rot_val)))
h,w,c = im.shape
p = Polygon((0,0),(0,w-1),(h-1,w-1),(h-1,0))
print("Line is",end = " ")
print(L)
print("Polygon is",end = " ")
print(p)
print("intersection is",end = " ")
print(p.intersection(L))
intersection = p.intersection(L)
```

Output:

```
Line is Line2D(Point2D(466, 838), Point2D(467, -459189054634.429))
Polygon is Polygon(Point2D(0, 0), Point2D(0, 1675), Point2D(931, 1675), Point2D(931, 0))
intersection is []
```

But If I run this code,

```
p = Polygon(Point2D(0, 0), Point2D(0, 1675), Point2D(931, 1675), Point2D(931, 0))
l = Line2D(Point2D(466, 838), Point2D(467, -459189054634.429))
print(l.intersection(p))
```

I am getting the correct intersection.

Comment: Please paste the code, not the picture of the code

Comment: I hope it is clear now.

Comment: You are using `h` and `w` before they're getting their value. Also, you have to be very careful with `math` functions inside sympy. For symbolic calculations, you should use the sympy equivalents.